# Whatsapp-like app

Tags: android, contacts

i am developing an app like "whatsapp" for which i want display contacts on my content (between header and footer) from my android phone so what can i do that task?

i tried this but it doesnt work.

```
function displayContact1() {
alert('Clicked');
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";
    options.multiple=true;
    var filter = [ "displayName", "phoneNumbers", "photos" ];
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, displayContact, onContactError, options);
var myContacts = new Object();

   // Default image path for the profile image 
   var defaultImagePath = $("#defaultImagePath").attr('src');

    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
    {

        if( contacts[i].phoneNumbers == null )
        continue;

       // Checks for the image 
        var img = contacts[i].photos  != null ? contacts[i].photos[0].value : defaultImagePath;

        if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length)
        for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++)
        {
            var pNumber = contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value; 
            var name = contacts[i].displayName != null ? contacts[i].displayName: "No name";

           // To sort the names based on the starting letter  
           // Stores the names in that array 
           var index = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();

           if (typeof myContacts[index] == 'undefined')
           {
               myContacts[index] = new Array();
           }

           // cuts the large names 
           if( name.length > 35 )
           {
               name = name.substr(0,35)+"...";
           }
          // Push every details into an array. 
          myContacts[index].push({"name":name, "pNumber": pNumber, "img": img} );

        }

    }

      var arrayKeys = new Array(); 
      for (var key in myContacts )
      {
          arrayKeys.push( key );
      }

      // Sorts the array based on the key A, B , C etc 
      arrayKeys = arrayKeys.sort();

      for( i = 0 ; i < arrayKeys.length ; i++ )
      {
           var records =  myContacts[ arrayKeys[i] ];
           $("#contacts").append ("<li class='letter-head'>"+ arrayKeys[i]+"</li>");

         // Sort each names  
         records = records.sort( sortNames );

           for( var r_key in records  )
           {



                $("#contacts").append ( "<li><img src='"+ records[r_key].img+"' /> <span class='contact-name'>"+records[r_key].name + "</span><span class='contact-number'>" + records[r_key].pNumber +  "</span></li>");
           }

      }


        hide_loader();
        $('.addressBook').effect("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);


 }

 function sortNames(a, b )
 {
     return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look up the Android Developer Site before asking next time.
Google can help here too.
There's a "Contact Managet" Sample from Google or [THIS](https://code.google.com/p/android-binding/wiki/ContactManagerDemo#Layout) one.

Here's how you read the contact data: [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/index.html)

Here's how you create a custom listview: [LINK](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Here's a tutorial for a whole contacts list: [LINK](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/adapters/create_a_custom_adapter_for_contacts/)